# Meta tags decoding by Google

Tags: google-search, meta-tags, unicode

My site's CMS has some problems with reflecting correct cyrillic letters.
So, in source code of the page my meta description looks like the next:

```html
<meta content="&#x0417;&#x0434;&#x0435;&#x0441;&#x044c; &#x0432;&#x044b; &#x043c;&#x043e;&#x0436;&#x0435;&#x0442;&#x0435; &#x0437;&#x0430;&#x043a;&#x0430;&#x0437;&#x0430;&#x0442;&#x044c; &#x043f;&#x0438;&#x0440;&#x043e;&#x0436;&#x043d;&#x044b;&#x0435; macarons (&#x043c;&#x0430;&#x043a;&#x0430;&#x0440;&#x0443;&#x043d;&#x044b;) &#x043e;&#x043d;&#x043b;&#x0430;&#x0439;&#x043d;. &#x0412;&#x044b; &#x043c;&#x043e;&#x0436;&#x0435;&#x0442;." name="description">
```

The same situation is with all meta-tags, which include `<meta name="" content="">`.

I think that this is because of Unicode escape sequence.

My question is:
Is Google able to decode these symbols into the correct characters to show a normal snippet in the SERP?

Currently the snippets of the site look normal, but I need to be sure that Google can read and decode Unicode escape sequences.

Is it normal from Google's point of view to get meta-tags in such a format?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and faster to just fix the cms?

Comment: @bybe This is a real problem for our developer to fia that because of specificity of CMS we use.

Comment: We will change or CMS, but it requires some time, so I need to be sure Google will decode my meta-tags correctly.

Comment: the easiest way to check your site is Fetch as Googlebot in Webmaster Tools https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en see how it render the title and description.

Comment: @Bala Have tried it, but it shows me the same html codes like descripted in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Character references like `&#x0417;` have been part of HTML for a long, long time, and they are frequently used for various reasons. Google is known to support them (as you say), and it would be very odd for it to drop the support. So from the SEO point of view, there is no need to get rid of such references.

The main problem with character references is that they are difficult to write and read to human beings, thereby making maintenance more difficult and even error-prone. But this is not relevant if the references are programmatically generated e.g. by a CMS.